# undefined reference with member implelementation of a templated class

Tags: c++, templates, undefined-reference

This is wholy mysterious to me. I'm using g++ on ubuntu, and this is some of my code (with class names change, but nothing else because I'm still using stubs everywhere):

**Bob.hpp**

```
template <class A>
class Bob : public Jack<Chris, A>
{
    public: 

        Bob(int x1, int x2, float x3 = 1.0, float x4 = 2.0, float x5 = 3.0) throw(Exception);
        virtual ~Bob();
};
```

I implemented in another file like this:

**Bob.cpp**

```
template <class A>
Bob<A>::Bob(int x1, int x2, float x3, float x4, float x5) throw(Exception)
{

}

template <class A>
Bob<A>::~Bob()
{

}
```

and I used it like this:

**main.cpp**

```
int main()
{
    Bob<Alice> instance(1, 2);
}
```

Compiling with:

```
g++ -c Bob.cpp -o Bob.o
g++ -c main.cpp -o main.o
g++ -L"libs" -llib main.o Bob.o prog
```

gives me 
    main.o: In function `main':
    main.cpp:(.text+0x1fd): undefined reference to`Bob::Bob(int, int, float, float, float)'
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

I am completely stumped. Changing the order with the g++ linking stage makes no difference. Compiling the object files generates no problems. And Why an undefined reference when I implemented the constructor? If anyone could shed any light on this, it's be much appreciated.

Comment: See [Why can't I separate the definition of my templates class from its declaration and put it inside a .cpp file?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.12) from the C++ FAQ Lite.

Comment: @James McNellis: Why not make this an answer? :)

Comment: @Merlyn: I didn't have time to write up a high-quality answer, and it's generally considered bad form just to post a link to another site as an answer without at least summarizing the linked content.

Comment: @Jame McNellis: Gotcha.  I usually do that cause I'm obsessive, but good to know it's accepted practice.

Comment: @Merlyn: See e.g. [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) or [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7515/why-is-linking-bad) on meta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the code from Bob.cpp into Bob.hpp. When the compiler sees the definitions of `Bob::Bob` and `Bob::~Bob` in Bob.cpp, it does not know what types of Bob are actually going to be instantiated (i.e. `Bob<int>` vs `Bob<SomeClass>` and the code for them isn't generated.
   Alternatively, you can still place the code in the Bob.cpp file, but you need to declare which types of Bob are going to be instantiated, e.g.:
Inside of Bob.cpp:

```
template
class Bob<Alice>;
```

Answer (score 1):

The declarations and definitions of the class template member functions should all be in the same header file.

When compiling `Bob.cpp`, the compiler has both the declarations and the definitions available. At this point the compiler does not need to generate any definitions for template classes, since there are no instantiations. When the compiler compiles `main.cpp`, there is an instantiation: template class `Bob<Alice>`. At this point the compiler has the declarations but no definitions!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the issues raised by others, libraries must come last on the GCC command line. Instead of:

```
g++ -L"libs" -llib main.o Bob.o prog
```

you want:

```
g++ -L"libs"  main.o Bob.o prog -llib
```

Comment: A valid comment, but not really an answer to the question. I did know this, the order ways a leftover from another fixing attempt where I changed include and linking order a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you think the constructor of `Bob<Alice>` should be defined? It wasn't defined in Bob.cpp, because there was no mention of a `Bob<Alice>` in Bob.cpp. There was a *template*, which could have been used to define `Bob<Alice>` when Bob.cpp was compiled into Bob.o, but it wasn't.

Put the template definition in Bob.hpp, or `Bob<Alice>` in Bob.cpp.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It's nice and concise so I would accept it, but others have a little more "meat" and deserve it a bit more.